# JsonIgnore and non-supported collection objects

Tags: .net-core, system.text.json

It seems that the System.Text.Json serializer doesn't take into account JsonIgnore attributes when executing - I get this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'The collection type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,Test.TestObject]' is not supported.'
```

when executing this code:

```
public class TestObject 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TestObjects : Dictionary<int, TestObject>
{ }

public class test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public TestObjects TestObjects { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = new test();
        var s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(m);
        Debugger.Break();
}
```

Documentation for the new serializer is a little sparse - am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just seen that this is a "feature" that is being addressed soon - https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/40413